# Combine aggregate level values with lower level detail

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I would like to aggregate data at level A and also show detail for one level down, say B.
Here is my query that aggregates the amounts at a product_line level (A).

```
SELECT
  pl.business_unit AS "BU"
 ,p.prod_line
 ,SUM(i.inv_amt) AS "Amount"
FROM   invoice i
LEFT   JOIN product p ON p.item_num = i.item_num
LEFT   JOIN product_level pl ON pl.pl_num = p.pl_num
WHERE  i.date BETWEEN '01-APR-2014' AND '30-APR-2014'
GROUP  BY pl.business_unit
         ,p.prod_line
HAVING SUM(i.inv_amt) > 500000
```

In the `invoice` table I have a `item_desc` field (level B). All item descriptions roll up to a product line description but if I add `item_desc` to the main query it won't aggregate correctly. I have tried all types of subqueries in `FROM and SELECT` with no correct result. I haven't used sub queries before but think that is what I need. If so, how would I accomplish having aggregation at the `prod_line` level while including the `item_desc` for each line? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you post some sample data with desired results?  Since you mention it doesn't `SUM` correctly, that seems like it must have different values per BU/Product Line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the product line is a one to one mapping to item_desc, then you can add in a MAX(item_desc) to your query

```
SELECT
 pl.business_unit AS "BU"
 ,p.prod_line
 ,max(p.item_desc)
 ,SUM(i.inv_amt) AS "Amount"
FROM   invoice i
LEFT   JOIN product p ON p.item_num = i.item_num
LEFT   JOIN product_level pl ON pl.pl_num = p.pl_num
WHERE  i.date BETWEEN '01-APR-2014' AND '30-APR-2014'
GROUP  BY pl.business_unit
         ,p.prod_line
HAVING SUM(i.inv_amt) > 500000
```